# how to add android expandable list view to mapview..?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my programme there is a map view and I have extends MapActivity to my class. but now I want to add  **ExpandableListView** to that programme. I am add adapter class that extends BaseExpandableListAdapter as inner class.so how to add ExpandableList to programe without extends ExpandableListView.
can't add

```
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
registerForContextMenu(getExpandableListView());
```

lines without extend ExpandableListView.
any other possible way..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am did successfully with this [example](http://en.wikicode.org/index.php/Custom_ExpandableListView) 
 It shows how to make ExpandableListView without extending ExpandableListView class